# Import website "Source" slows down after a few iterations

Tags: performance-tuning, import

I am using

```
Import[link, "Source"]
```

to import the source of several hundreds of thousands of webpages in a while loop to process them. Each iteration has the same complexity, but I notice that after a while the import rate slows down from several per second to one per several seconds and even slower. Considering that the processing of the imported source strings is trivial, I suspect that it is the `Import[link, "Source"]` command that becomes slower after some time. (If I quit the kernel and restart the while loop, it starts importing quickly again, and then slows down again.) To make sure that there is no memory slowdown, each import is stored in the same variable `data`, which I clear via `data=.;` at the end of each iteration, so that no memory persists across several iterations.

Is this expected behavior? Is there some way to make sure that `Import` does not slow down over time?

Code example:

```
Dynamic[i]
```

and

```
list={};
Do[
  link="https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/"<>ToString[i];
  data=Import[link, "Source"];
  If[Length[StringPosition[data, "Email"]] > 0,
     AppendTo[list,{StringSplit[ StringSplit[data, "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\""][[2]], "\" />"][[1]], link}];
  ];
,{i,1,258999}];
```

I used the Mathematica stackexchange website here for demonstration purposes only, so the code does not accomplish anything useful.

Comment: Have you checked whether your computer is running out of memory?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I checked, it does not run out of memory.

Comment: Could you add the actual code used when you encountered this problem?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of requests in a short time might trigger (for example) DDOS/flood detection in your operating system, router, ISP, or anywhere else in your network. If you add a short delay between requests, perhaps that will prevent this slowdown?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have added a code snippet to the question.

Comment: @CarlLange That's a good point! Perhaps that is actually what is happening... But one argument against that is - if I stop the code and restart the kernel, it begins downloading fast again before slowing down. If ISP had throttled my connection, there shouldn't be anything I could do locally to crank the speed back up.

Comment: @Kagaratsch usually there is a request `backoff` if too many have been supplied but after you wait that long it should be fine. `Import` might have handling this baked in (or might use an internally library that does)